# Выбрасывать исключение в методах с указанным возвращаемым типом

Tags: php

правильно ли выбрасывать исключение, если у метода задано возвращаемое значения ? Могут ли быть ошибки ?

Например:

```
function getId() : int {
   if(туда-сюда) { ... return $id; }
   throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: *Могут ли быть ошибки ?* - вряд ли мой опыт является показателем, но я уверен, что могут, куда без них...

Answer (score 1):

Таким образом можно выбрасывать исключения. Будем рассматривать на *вашем* примере. Выполнение не прошло условную конструкцию `if` и дальше по коду идет `throw new Exception()`, тип возвращаемого значения функции `:int`. Т.е. когда мы выбросили исключение - означает что процесс который выполнялся **до**, нам **не интересен** => нам уже **не важно** функция ли это или нет, возвращаемый тип, или что-то иное; У нас появляется задача "поймать" это исключение и **обработать** его как нужно. Можно предстваить, что при выбросе исключения дается выбор: Обрабатывать исключение, абстрагируясь от предидущего кода, или же вернуть другой "неожиданный" результат.

```
function foo($bar): int
{
    if($bar)
        return 1;

    throw new Exception();
}
```

Далее уже "системный код" поймает исключение и скажет что оно было выброшено и укажет причину такого поведения, он **забудет** о том что выполнялась функция `foo` и будет поступать по иным инструкциям(Аналог этого можно привести ЧП, случившаяся в городе, и все люди вместо того чтобы им вернуться домой вынуждены выполнять другие действия `catch` "системный код", забыв про дом `foo`).

Еще один пример с тем как указать инструкции выполнения при исключении и вернуть все таки долгожданный `int`:

```
function foo($bar): int
{

    try {

        if($bar)
        return 1;

        throw new Exception();
    } catch($e Exception) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Во втором случае мы указываем инструкции по исполнению и **можем продолжить** выполнение и возврат значения из функции(Случилась ЧП, но мы все равно пошли домой, и вернулись)ю

P.S.: "системный код" - код языка С, в который интерпретируется php.

:)